# Notify user that download is complete in Newsstand app

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, newsstand-kit

Is there any way to use local notifications to alert a user that a magazine that they are downloading via newsstand in the background has completed downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you are using an NKAssetDownload to get the newstand content. Then you start the download with a NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate:

```
[assetDownload downloadWithDelegate:self];
```

When the download completes succesfully, you get a callback on

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL;
```

in which implementation you could use a UILocalNotification to alert the user.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I had a breakpoint in this method, but it wasn't firing because background downloads had got turned off in the device's store settings.